# python: how to make list with all lowercase?

Tags: python, string, list, dataset, lowercase

Suppose I have some data like:

```
data[0] = ['I want to make everything lowercase']
data[1] = ['How Do I Do It']
data[2] = ['With A Large DataSet']
```

How do I repeatedly call the lower() function on all the elements of `data`, to make all the of strings in lowercase?

I have tried `{k.lower(): v for k, v in data.items()}`, but I get an error saying that `'list' object has no attribute 'items'`.

I have also tried using `.lower()` and it is giving me the same `AtrributeError`.

Comment: data is not a dictionary,its a list that's why doesnt have items method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your list *data* like this:

```
data = ['I want to make everything lowercase', '', '']
data = [k.lower() for k in data]
```

if your list *data* is a list of string list:

```
data = [['I want to make everything lowercase'], ['']]
data = [[k.lower()] for l in data for k in l]
```

the fact is that list don't has attribute 'items'

Comment: Is the one below the nested for-loops in python?

Comment: Yes cohsta. The second solution has nested for loops

Answer (score 5):

You need a list comprehension, not a dict comprehension:

```
lowercase_data = [v.lower() for v in data]
```

Comment: It's still giving me Attribute error saying list object has no attribute lower

Comment: @cohsta - You have list of list data structure. Above solution only works for list data structure.

Comment: @Amber - Requesting you to make your solution working for list of list

Comment: I'm sorry I did not give a sufficient informations. What @DineshPundkar said is correct.